# Any two reflections of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are conjugate in $I(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, isometry, reflection

> Let $H_1,H_2$ be arbitrary hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $H_1
>  \cap H_2 \neq \{ \} $
>
> Then, reflections $R_{H_1},R_{H_2}$ satisfies
> $R_{H_1}R_{H_2}=R(h,\alpha)$ where $h$ is some $n-2$ dimensional
> structure s.t $H_1 \cap H_2 = h$ and $R(h,\alpha)$ is a rotation about
> $h$ through angle $\alpha$.
>
> Also, there exist another hyperplane $H_3$ s.t
> $R_{H_3}R_{H_1}=R(h,\alpha)$.
>
> Thus, $R_{H_1}R_{H_2}=R_{H_3}R_{H_1}$.
>
> This gives us $R_{H_1}R_{H_2}(R_{H_1})^{-1}=R_{H_3}$, so $R_{H_2},
>  R_{H_3}$ are conjugate.
>
> And, as $H_1,H_2$ were chosen arbitrarily, any two reflections are
> conjugate.

This is just my rough idea, which needs more details.
But, I couldn't really add any more details.

First of all, does my rough idea make sense?

Actually, my first goal was to show that $R_{H_1},R_{H_2}$ are conjugate, but the conclusion here is different from what I aimed for.

What do I need to consider if I want to show two arbitrary reflections are conjugate?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This seems awfully complicated. Why not show there is an isometry (I assume that's what the $I$ stands for) carrying $H_1$ to $H_2$. Conjugate $R_{H_1}$ by that isometry and you have $R_{H_2}$.

Comment: Your argument does not seem to establish the result for two given arbitrary reflections. You only get it for one of them and a weird other one. Can you figure out how to reverse engineer $H_1$ and $H_2$? Otherwise, this doesn't do much of anything.

Comment: @TedShifrin Before this approach, I did as you suggested. However, I wasn't 100% sure that there exists an isometry that sends $H_1$ to $H_2$. Is this true because an isometry is one-to-one mapping? So, an isometry should send a hyperplane to another hyperplane? However, I thought this was not a sufficient reason. What are the other reasons?

Comment: Well, yes, isometries map hyperplanes to hyperplanes (I have no idea what your course has for structure) by basic linear algebra. But you still have to prove that given any two hyperplanes, there is an isometry carrying one to the other. You have to do some explicit mathematics here.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks! Would picking two arbitrary points in each hyperplane be the first step of the explicit method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is hard to understand. What is "some $n−2$ dimensional structure", for example?

But it looks like you are trying to prove with your approach that any two reflections about intersecting hyperplanes are conjugated by a reflection. That is true. Let $u, v$ be the normal vectors of the hyperplanes $H_u, H_w$. We can assume that $\|u\|=\|v\|=1$. Let $w$ be $u+v$ and $H_w$ be the hyperplane containing $H_u\cap H_v$ and perpendicular to $w$ (since $H_u\cap H_v$ is perpendicular to both $u$ and $v$, it is perpendicular to $w$). Then the reflection about $H_w$ will take $u$ to $v$, $H_u$ to $H_w$ and will conjugate  the reflection about $H_u$ to the reflection about $H_v$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I could easily understand all steps except for the last line "and will conjugate the reflections $R_{H_u}, R_{H_v}$. Could you give me a little more detail on this part? I wonder how we could conclude as $R_{H_w}R_{H_u}(R_{H_w})^{-1}=R_{H_v}$ by the fact $H_w$ takes $u$ to $v$, $H_u$ to $H_v$.

Comment: A conjugation of a reflection about hyperplane $\Pi$ by an isometry $g$ is a reflection about the hyperplane $g(\Pi)$.